# Error occurred when I use variables in the shift operation of C

Tags: c

Last night, my friend tell me a situation as following shows:

in c/c++ ,we write two lines code like this:

```
int a = 0;
printf("%d\n", 1 << -1);
printf("%d\n", 1 << (a-1));
```

It is amazing there are two different results, previous is 0, and the other is -2147483648.

We do not know why, and anyone can give me a help.

any word is welcome.

Comment: It is undefined behavior, meaning that _anything_ can happen, including crashes, random stuff getting printed or the program appearing to work correctly. There is no point in trying to understanding the reason of a particular program behavior once undefined behavior is invoked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Having a negative operand on the right hand side of a left-shift operator is undefined behavior in C. You shouldn't be amazed at any results from doing it.

Answer (score 4):

Signed integers on right-hand side are undefined behavior in the C language.

> ISO 9899:1999 6.5.7 Bit-wise shift operators §3
>
> The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands. The type
>   of the result is that of the promoted left operand. If the value of
>   the right operand is negative or is greater than or equal to the width
>   of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

The result is undefined if the right operand of a shift expression is negative or if the right operand is greater than or equal to the number of bits in the (promoted) left operand. No shift operation is performed if the right operand is zero (0).

[Check this msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/336xbhcz.aspx)